# Unable to grab element by className even if I see it in the browser console

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

So I am having a very frustrating issue.

I am trying to grab a HTML element with React/JS which exists only in a library, not in my code so I can't use useRef or anything like that.

If I do this:

```js
  useEffect(() => {    
    const handleContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('handle-container');
    console.log({ handleContainer: handleContainer[0] });
  }, [document]);
```

It prints: `{ handleContainer: undefined }`

But with this:

```js
  useEffect(() => {    
    const handleContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('handle-container');
    console.log({ handleContainer });
  }, [document]);
```

It prints this:

[image]

I am trying to disable the right click event on that element.
Like this:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('handle-container')?.[0]?.setAttribute('oncontextmenu', 'return false;');
```

But I am failing.

Any ideas?
Any ideas?

Comment: why the "?" in `document.getElementsByClassName('handle-container')?.[0]?`? 

You can grab the first element by doing `document.getElementsByClassName('handle-container')[0]`

Comment: also use quotes-> console.log({ "handleContainer": handleContainer[0] });

Comment: hm the mystery to me is why it won't console.log... does `console.log({ handleContainer: handleContainer.item(0) }) work?

Comment: @Max that's a Typescript thing to check `null`s but soon it will be part of the JS standard. You use it now actually depending on the transpiler you use. https://github.com/davidyaha/ecmascript-optionals-proposal

Comment: @DCR that's not relevant. Without quotes is ok. https://levelup.gitconnected.com/5-ways-to-log-an-object-to-the-console-in-javascript-7b995c56af5a

Comment: @DanOswalt `TS2339: Property 'item' does not exist on type 'void'.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This most likely because the console is displaying the current state of the HTMLCollection being referenced using `console.log({ handleContainer });` over the snapshot of the first element (which may not exist yet) which is happening when you perform `console.log({ handleContainer: handleContainer[0] });`...

Could you try adding a timeout like below and seeing what happens? This will hopefully give enough time for the library and DOM to load up and make it queryable at effect function run...

```
 useEffect(() => {    
   setTimeout(() => {
        const handleContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('handle-container');
        console.log({ handleContainer: handleContainer[0] });
   }, 1000);
 }, [document]);
```

If this shows the expected element, then it would indicate that when the effect is called without a timer the class element that needs to be referenced using `{ handleContainer: handleContainer[0] }` does not yet exist but because the console is displaying a reference of the HTMLCollection object using `{ handleContainer }` it would would still display it in the console as it is not dereferencing it from the children array.

Refs: [MDN - HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)